# Why is showing that $ker(T_A) = \vec 0$ the same as showing that a linear transformation is one-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine if the standard matrix $A$ representing the linear transformation is one-to-one.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&0\\3&-4\end{bmatrix}$

Answer: Yes

---

My question: When determining if multiplication by A is a one-to-one linear transformation, is it equivalent to determine if $ker(A)=\vec 0$ ? In other words, is the following method always a valid way to determine if $T_A$ is a one-to-one linear transformation?

$T_A$ is one-to-one if $ker$($T_A$)$=\vec 0$ , i.e, $A\vec x=\vec 0$ only has the trivial solution $\vec x=\vec 0$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\2&0&0\\3&-4&0\end{bmatrix}$ $\rightarrow$ $x=0,y=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\vec x=\vec 0$

**So $T_A$ is one-to-one.**

I am confused about this method because if $ker$($T_A$)$=\vec 0$ then that means the only vector that is mapped to $\vec 0$ after the linear transformation is $\vec 0$. So this only shows that the there is one input vector for the output vector  $\vec 0$. However, a one-to-one linear transformation means that each unique vector in the domain maps to only one vector  in the range. So why don't I have to show all vectors have this property and just show that zero vector has this property?

So my question is why is showing that the kernel of the transformation is $\vec 0$ enough to show that the transformation is one-to-one?

Comment: The method above is also equivalent to showing that the column vectors are linearly independent. And the column space corresponds to the range of the transformation. So if the column vectors are linearly independent does that mean that each output vector in the range is unique, meaning that the linear transformation is one-to-one?

Comment: If $Ax=Ay$ then $A(x-y)=0$, that is $x-y\in\ker A$. Now if $\ker A=\{0\}$, then necessarily $x-y=0$ hence $x=y$, hence $A$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you have mentioned in your comment, the span of the column vectors of A (column space) represent the range of the linear transformation. This is because when you multiply the given standard matrix by column vector of the right number of rows,

$$A\vec x = \vec b$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&0\\3&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x-y\\2x\\3x-4y\end{bmatrix}$$

your resultant vector $\vec b$ is a linear system representing all possible linear combinations, i.e., all possible output vectors (range) reached by multiplying any input vector $\vec x$ (domain) by the standard matrix $A$ (transformation).

So since the **column space** corresponds to the **range**, if you end up with the trivial solution for your homogeneous augmented matrix that means your column vectors are linearly independent, in other words all output vectors in the range are also linearly independent. This then implies that your linear transformation is one-to-one because your output vectors cannot be expressed in terms of other output vectors, meaning that the preimage of each output vector was unique.

Comment: Why does having linearly independent output vectors mean that the linear transformation is independent? Is it because $\vec b$ consists of $\vec x$ and that $\vec x$  must be the zero vector in order to make each of the equations in $\vec b$ equal to 0?

Comment: Having linearly independent output vectors mean that there does not exist any input vectors (excluding $\vec 0$) $\vec x = (c_1,c_2,...,c_i)$ or $\vec x = (x,y)$ in this case, such that  $x\vec v_1 + y\vec v_2 = \vec 0$ $\rightarrow x(1,2,3)+y(-1,0,-4) = \vec 0$. Therefore, each image(output vector) has a unique preimage(input vector) and so the linear transformation is 1-1.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose You say that KerT ={0}

Then Suppose For two vectors u and v
.T(u) = T(v)
Implies that T(u) -T(v) = 0 Since T is Linear map so it
Implies T(u-v)=0.

But Ker T ={ 0 }
So u-v=0

Hence u= v

Then T is one one for any vector

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if by one-to-one you mean bijective, then your matrix A is evidently not bijective as is represents a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ which you can see dimensionnaly is never one-to-one, even if you add a column of zeros. In particular, if your add a column of zeros, the kernel of your matrix will no longer be trivial as any vector of the form $$(0,0,\alpha ),$$ will be sent to $0$.

Now having a trivial kernel does make a matrix **injective** which implies directly that it is surjective if the matrix is square -> it is one-to-one (you can try to see it dimensionnaly, or with the rank theorem). However this is not the case here.

Comment: Why does having a trivial kernel imply that the matrix is injective(one-to-one)? If the kernel is trivial then that means the only vector mapped to the zero vector after a linear transformation is the zero vector itself. This trivial kernel only considers one vector ($\vec 0$). So how does showing that the kernel is trivial enough to show that every unique vector has one output vector (injective)?

Comment: @Joshua Freeman Please note that one-to-one means injective. In the same terminology one often says onto for surjective, whereas bijective would be one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 0):

How:
*The kernel of a linear transformation $T$ only contains the null element*

can be equivalent to:
*$T$ is a one-to-one function*

---

Because $T$ is a linear transformation, $T$ has two guaranteed properties, for any vector space, including a vector space of matrices:

$
\bbox[linen, 3px, border: 1px solid tan]
{ \;
T(\vec 0) = \vec 0
\; }
$

$
\bbox[linen, 3px, border: 1px solid tan]
{ \;
\alpha T(\vec u) + \beta T(\vec v) = T(\alpha \vec u + \beta \vec v)
\;}
$

If $T(\vec x) = \vec 0 \implies \vec x = \vec 0$, then:

$$
\begin {align}
T(\vec u) = T(\vec v) 
& \implies T(\vec u) - T(\vec v) = \vec 0 \\
& \implies T(\vec u - \vec v) = \vec 0 \\
& \implies \vec u - \vec v = \vec 0 \\
& \implies \vec u = \vec v
\end {align} 
$$

and $T$ is one-to-one.

$
\bbox[linen, 3px, border: 1px solid tan]
{ \;
\ker(T) = \{ \vec 0 \}
\; \text {and} \; T(\vec u) = T(\vec v) \implies \vec u = \vec v
\;
}
$